# X commands do not start from my at job

Tags: shell, shell-script, x11, at

I'm learning about Linux scheduling commands including `at`, `cron`, `sleep` etc. I'm trying to launch `gedit` after x minutes via the `at` command. This is what I have:

```
kedar@i5 ~ $ at now + 1 minute
at now + 1 minute
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> ./s.sh
at> <EOT>
job 18 at Fri Aug 15 13:21:00 2014
```

The contents of **s.sh** (-rwxr--r--):

```
#!/bin/sh
#set $DISPLAY=:0
echo "Created on" `date` >t.txt
gedit #(also tried /usr/bin/gedit and `gedit` and systen(/usr/bin/gedit))
```

After 1 minute, t.txt is created with the expected contents. However, `gedit` is not launched. For that matter, none of my programs(`firefox`,`xcalc`,`xfce4-terminal` etc) can be launched this way via `at`.

Strange thing is, when I run `./s.sh` in bash, `gedit` opens up fine.

Also I tried running `at` (from a file - if this is at all correct) as:

```
kedar@i5 ~ $ at now + 1 minute -f ./s.sh
```

I guess there's something wrong with the way I'm using `at` with the shell script. Also can't I use `at` without a shell script? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the display variable, but this is done as:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=":0"
gedit
```

and then

```
at now + 1 minute -f test.sh
```

works for me on `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`

Comment: Running `xhost+` outputs: access control disabled, clients can connect from any host. Tried uncommenting the display var, still no go.

Comment: Totally! That worked! `export DISPLAY=":0"` is apparently not the same as `set $DISPLAY=:0`. I have a lot to learn.. Thanks a bunch!